# How to load more markers and rotate each marker image in different direction?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-markers

I am creating a map application in which I am loading nearly 70000 markers. I need to rotate each marker in different direction(degree). If i use single image URL in the icon the maps loads it.

```
        const image = {
          url: require('../../assets/images/some.svg'),

          fillColor: '#FF4500',
          fillOpacity: 0.6,

          size: new google.maps.Size(75, 75),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
          scale: 0.5,
          rotation: 20,
        };
```

But i could not able to rotate the image. If i use the SVG path i could able to rotate, but the page crashing.

```
       const image = {
         path:
            'M 3405.12 351.005 v -0.013 c -0.03 0 -0.07 0.006 -0.11 0.007 s -0.09 -0.007 -0.14 -0.007 v 0.014 c -4.37 0.155 -7.87 13.2 -7.87 17.6 v 14.183 a 1.212 1.212 0 0 0 1.22 1.212 h 13.56 a 1.219 1.219 0 0 0 1.22 -1.212 V 368.01 C 3413 363.613 3409.49 351.138 3405.12 351.005 Z',
          fillColor: '#FF4500',
          fillOpacity: 0.6,

          size: new google.maps.Size(75, 75),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),
          scale: 0.5,
          rotation: 120,
        };
```

Comment: are you use any node module

Comment: With Image as URL : https://jsfiddle.net/z4wu6c8g/1/
With SVG path https://jsfiddle.net/z4wu6c8g/1/

Comment: Is your application crashing because of the rotation or because of the really big amount of markers to rotate? Do you get any error in console or script just doesn't respond for a while?

Comment: @channasmcs No. I am accessing api directly

Comment: @MaciejTrojniarz Its because of try to  rotating the big amount of markers. Check my Fiddle sample. One with single image(URL's will not take rotation property) for all the markers, the page loads fine. The second with SVG path (I could roate the SVG path) which is crashing

Comment: The rotation whcih i set in the image "rotation: 120" will be dynamic from the database along with lat lan.

Comment: Both jsfiddle shows the version with gif image

Comment: I think this is then the limitation of the browser/laptop/pc performance that this will not work. I would challenge the need of rendering 70 000 markers on google map. Maybe you should have some kind of lazy loading of those markers based on detection of the what is rendered